# PHP: How to keep UTF-8 encoding when copying data into one file

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I am trying to copy data from four files into one file. When Copying I lose all special characters like é and all others.

This is how I try to copy the data:

```
#Contact all files into one file
    $content = file_get_contents($sweden);
    file_put_contents($outputFile, "\xEF\xBB\xBF" . $content, FILE_APPEND);

    $content = file_get_contents($norway);
    file_put_contents($outputFile, "\xEF\xBB\xBF" . $content, FILE_APPEND);

    $content = file_get_contents($denmark);
    file_put_contents($outputFile, "\xEF\xBB\xBF" . $content, FILE_APPEND);

    $content = file_get_contents($easyorder);
    $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8', 'auto');
    file_put_contents($outputFile, "\xEF\xBB\xBF" . $content, FILE_APPEND);
```

Can you give me a hint what I do wrong?

Thanks!